# Auto input user and password to connect to an SFTP server

Tags: curl, ssh, command-line, command-line-interface, sftp

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10

Objective - Connect to a designated SFTP server without having to manually input any passwords.

Issues - I'm trying to connect to a sftp server to access the files. However I have to manually input the password once I connect. As I have log into a server with multiple user credentials, this makes downloading files from the servers very time consuming as I have to log in each time.

I have tried the following without success.

`curl sftp://sftp.host.com:/csv -u user:pwrd` -found out that SFTP isn't supported with curl

`sftp user@sftp.host.com:/csv` -I connected with this one however I have to input the pwrd manually each time.

`ssh sftp.host.com:/csv` -Can't get the host name to recongnise and connect. Also tried user@sftp.host.com:/csv in here. I read up about how I could use a shh key to authenticate to avoid the password but if I have to provide multiple users log ins (100+) wouldn't it take a large amount of time to create and place these keys in the first place.

For the `sftp` version I thought perhaps this could be done `echo pwd | user@sftp.host.com:/csv` and I could delay the input if I used the `sleep` command, so it enters the password after. Also tried `sftp user@sftp.host.com:/csv | { print pwrd}`. Neither seem possible however based on how the command line works.

Can someone confirm If `curl` is actually the right way to go and there is a trick to getting the sftp to be supported. Maybe `sftp` is the way to go and I'm just going about the password input incorrectly. Or is `ssh` what I should be doing and theres an easy way to generate and place multiple keys (though I'd still have to do the initial log in so it seems to just be a step after my problem)? Or there is something else I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a script with lftp

`SFTP_SERVER="sftp.host.com:/csv"`
`SFTP_USER="user"`
`SFTP_PWD="pwd"`

`lftp sftp://$SFTP_USER:$SFTP_PWD@$SFTP_SERVER`

Running this script allows me to not have to input the password manually but the `*.csv` command doesn't seem to work within this, so if you wanted to `get *.csv` you won't be able to download all files.